# Getting max values in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to get the max value in datagridview that contains numbers only?

Here is the code. It gets all of the values.

```
    Dim Max As Integer = 0

    For Each rws As DataGridViewRow In dgvItems.Rows
        If Max < rws.Cells(1).Value Then Max = rws.Cells(1).Value
    Next
```

Comment: maximum value in a column right?

Comment: yes. but values that is numeric only

Comment: what is the problem with your correct code?

Comment: i want to get the values that contains numeric only : sample data 
07136
07138
07138-b

the result should be 07138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 If IsNumeric(rws.Cells(1).Value) Then
    If Max < rws.Cells(1).Value Then Max = rws.Cells(1).Value
 End If
```